# Powershell: IF Statement and Timer.Elapsed

Tags: powershell-3.0, rdp

The purpose of my code, is to run a RDP connection (in a custom shell) on thinclients. Whenever the RDP logon is cancelled, or the RDP connection gets terminated, the logon window will appear again. This will present the user with their logon screen at all times.

Also because the RD Broker maintaines 15 minutes handshake timeout, I wanted to run a refresh every 15 minutes, when they session is not open already. So I had to find some sort of way to detect if the user wasn't logged onto a RD host.

The script is running nicely. Allthough always interested in more clever ways to run this.

```
Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe C:\Connection\Terminal-Server.RDP
$previous_Handles = 0

While(1) {

    $process = Get-Process mstsc
    $timer = New-Object System.Threading.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 900000
    $timer.Enabled = $true
    $timer.Autoreset = $true
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier TimerElapsed -Action {Stop-Process -Id $process.Id}

    if((($process.Handles -le 700) -and ($previous_Handles -ge 700) -or ($process -eq $null)))
            {

            Stop-Process -Id $process.Id
            $previous_Handles = 0
            $Timer.Stop()
            Unregister-Event -Force -SourceIdentifier TimerElapsed
            Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe C:\Connection\Terminal-Server.RDP
            }

    elseif($process.Handles -ge 925) {

            $process = Get-Process mstsc
            $previous_Handles = $process.Handles
            $Timer.Stop()
            Start-Sleep -m 500
            Unregister-Event -Force -SourceIdentifier TimerElapsed
            }


    else {

            Start-Sleep -m 500
            $previous_Handles = $process.Handles
            $Timer.Start()
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will open the RDP window one second after the process has been found to be closed and will continue to loop until the PowerShell process is stopped.

```
while($true)
{
    $RDPprocess = Start-Process mstsc -ArgumentList path-to.rdp -PassThru
    do {Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}
    until($RDPprocess.HasExited)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Pesistent13 :-) I'll see if I can cleanup the code using the start-proces variables. Allthough this works as well. I got the code up and and running now. But Always interested in more clever ways, since I'm new to powershell.